Is there any way to achieve static polymorphism in Kotlin?
I've run into a situation, where I got some classes that share the same interface:
sealed interface Animal {
    // "const static val nickname: String" ??
}

class Canidae: Animal {
    companion object {
        const val nickname = "dog"
    }
}

class Felidae: Animal {
    companion object {
        const val nickname = "cat"
    }
}

// and more ...

and I wanted to make a function that works like this:
inline fun<reified T: Animal, R> Animal.doSomething(f: (T) -> R): R =
    if (this is T) {
        f(this)
    } else {
        error("it's not a ${T.nickname}, it's a ${this.nickname}!") // but this simply can't compile
    }

I can assure that all classes which implement Animal have a compile-time constant nickname. Does there exist an approach of doSomething in Kotlin?
I've tried to just use reflections and enumerate over each derived class of Animal, and it surely worked. But that overcosts runtime resources, and it's tiring to maintain all nicknames inside a single function instead of where the class it associates with is defined. It would be very helpful if there's a more elegant way to do it.

What is the reason you need it to be a const? Why can't you just use val nickname: String in the interface and override it in the classes?

Could you describe the use case for this function? It's usually best to avoid runtime errors if you can get compile time errors instead

@Leviathan because then I would not be able to get nickname without an instance, but it should be a static property.

@Joffrey In the actual case the function returns a Result<R> type with more specific error information. And, the type of this could only be known at runtime.

Kotlin doesn't have the concept of static, but it has companion objects. Since companion objects are objects, you can make them implement interfaces.
You could leverage this in the following (admittedly over-engineered) approach:

use a different type to represent the family of Animal (or whatever term fits better in your case, but Canidae and Felidae are families according to my 30 seconds of Googling :D).
make Animal subclasses advertise their family as a property, so you can access the family of this in your function.
make the companion object of each animal class implement the Family interface, so you can use the class name in code to refer to the family of any given Animal subclass (you could instead create regular objects for each family, but using companions allows to refer to the family using the class name)

This gives the following:
sealed interface Animal {
    val family: Family<*>
}

interface Family<T : Animal> {
    val nickname: String
}

class Canidae: Animal {
    
    override val family get() = Canidae
    
    companion object : Family<Canidae> {
        override val nickname = "dog"
    }
}

class Felidae: Animal {
    
    override val family get() = Felidae
    
    companion object : Family<Felidae> {
        override val nickname = "cat"
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Animal, R> Animal.doSomething(family: Family<T>, f: (T) -> R): R =
    if (this is T) {
        f(this)
    } else {
        error("it's not a ${family.nickname}, it's a ${this.family.nickname}!")
    }


And you can use it this way:
animal.doSomething(Felidae) { println(it) }

This implementation has a drawback, though. You could by mistake make the Canidae class expose the Felidae family without compilation error.
We could fix this with even more over-engineering by making the Animal class recursively generic:
sealed interface Animal<T : Animal<T>> {
    val family: Family<T>
}

interface Family<T : Animal<T>> {
    val nickname: String
}

class Canidae: Animal<Canidae> {
    
    override val family get() = Canidae
    
    companion object : Family<Canidae> {
        override val nickname = "dog"
    }
}

class Felidae: Animal<Felidae> {
    
    override val family get() = Felidae
    
    companion object : Family<Felidae> {
        override val nickname = "cat"
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Animal<T>, R> Animal<*>.doSomething(family: Family<T>, f: (T) -> R): R =
    if (this is T) {
        f(this)
    } else {
        error("it's not a ${family.nickname}, it's a ${this.family.nickname}!")
    }


One downside of this is that every instance of Canidae or Felidae has a family backing field — which can be a big waste of memory if there are many instances.  But that's easily fixed: instead of a simple property, provide a getter such as override val family get() = Canidae.  Kotlin will then dispense with the backing field.  (The val in the interface promises that there will be a getter, but says nothing about how it'll be implemented, so you're free to provide the getter directly instead of getting the default property one.)

(Though if nickname were the only family-specific property, I'd be tempted to put that in the Animal interface directly and avoid the companion objects and Family interface altogether.)

@gidds right, I made family a computed property now, that's indeed better. Regarding nickname, I initially thought of just putting it in Animal as a computed property too, but then we can't refer to the nickname of the family that is passed to doSomething. In the error message, we need to be able to find it using just the class (statically) without having an instance.
